# How to calculate AVG of generated query in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query in mySQL that generates the difference between two columns that's limited to 100 entries and sorted by another column. It gives me a list of 100 values, and I want to be able to find the average of the generated answers from the query; I know how to find the AVG of all the differences, but I don't need that value.

My Query:

```
SELECT ABS(VAL1-VAL2)
FROM USER.TABLE1
ORDER BY JOB DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

What I want to get is how to find the average of this query's results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do it as follows:

```
SELECT AVG(t.result) 
FROM (SELECT ABS(VAL1-VAL2) AS result
      FROM USER.TABLE1
      ORDER BY JOB DESC
      LIMIT 100) t;
```